# How to find the installed plugin on elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is there way to find the installed plugin on elasticsearch? 
Currently there are few plugins installed but I don't know what are those plugin and how to access them. I know few of them, but I want a list of all plugin which are installed.

e.g few plugin url:

```
http:://<HOSTNAME>:9200/_plugin/bigdesk/#nodes
http:://<HOSTNAME>::9200/_plugin/kopf/#!/nodes
```

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu they are in /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins

Comment: I forgot, this also will list them all: sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When elasticsearch cluster is started it logs which plugins are loaded. Here example from my elastic log:

```
[2015-08-10 11:47:28,710][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Gorgeous George] loaded [analysis-decompound, analysis-combo, extended-analyze, analysis-stempel, analysis-worddelimiter2, analysis-icu], sites [HQ, head, inquisitor, bigdesk, kopf]
```

From [elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-plugins.html):

> Plugins can have "sites" in them, any plugin that exists under the
>   plugins directory with a _site directory, its content will be
>   statically served when hitting /_plugin/[plugin_name]/ url. Those can
>   be added even after the process has started.

Couple examples how to access above plugins:

```
http://localhost:9201/_plugin/HQ (case actually matters here)
http://localhost:9201/_plugin/inquisitor
```

You can also check which plugins are installed by looking into `plugins` directory in elastic installation directory.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this command:

```
bin>./elasticsearch-plugin list
```

it will list all installed plugins.
and their location is  in :

```
 /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin
```

Comment: elasticsearch-plugins : The term 'elasticsearch-plugins' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: @batmaci Edited

Comment: The above invocation is still incorrect for me for Elasticsearch 2.3.1 and 2.4.1.  I see the call being `./bin/plugin list`

Comment: this answer is for elastic 5.2 maybe it is different in 2.3